# Why this code does not work?

Tags: c++

Below is a simple code for sorting strings. It causes asserting error somewhere in the template library:

```
struct {
    bool operator()(string a, string b)
    {
       sort(a.begin(), a.end());
       sort(b.begin(), b.end());

       return a.compare(b);
    }
} mycompare;

void mySort(vector<string> &strvec)
{
    sort(strvec.begin(), strvec.end(), mycompare);  //LINE1

}

void test_mySort()
{
    vector<string> vec{ "abc", "bac", "ma", "acre", "reca", "care" };

    mySort(vec);

    cout << "After sort: " << endl;
    for (vector<string>::iterator ite = vec.begin(); ite != vec.end(); ite++)
    {
        cout << *ite << " ";
    }

}
```

LINE1 cannot execute.

Comment: Johnny, Johnny, Johnny... what's `LINE1`?  `struct {`?

Comment: "It causes asserting error somewhere in the template library" is not a proper problem description. Post the exact and full error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::string::compare` does not return a bool. It returns an int in three possible states, either negative (a < b), or 0 (a == b) or positive (a > b). When you convert that to a bool in the return statement of your comparator, it ends up being true if they are unequal, and false if they are equal. That does not satisfy the conditions that `std::sort` expects for its comparator. Just use this:

```
return a < b;
```

If you wanted to use `string::compare`, then you would use it like this:

```
return a.compare(b) < 0;
```